# Can't access nodes in xhtml document with multiple namespaces through xpath

Tags: php, xpath, curl, namespaces

Okay, so I'm trying to parse a xhtml site with curl and xpath.

The site has multiple namespaces:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:addthis="http://www.addthis.com/help/api-spec"     xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

I am trying to get all the urls from the site's pagination like this:

```
$url = [site_im_parsing];

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($url);  
$xpath = new Domxpath($dom);

$xpath->registerNamespace("x", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

$pages = $xpath->query('//x:div[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[1]/x:a');

for ($i = 0; $i < $pages->length; $i++) {

    echo $pages->item($i)->getAttribute('href');

}
```

This doesn't work. (The xpath to the pagination without the x-namespace should be right). Should I register all the namespaces and use them all somehow in the xpath query?

Best regards,
AB

// question update //

This is the part of the page I'm trying to parse:
(I want the href's)

```
<div class="pager">
    <table style="width:100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="current">1</span>  | 
                    <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/catalog?on_offer=1&amp;commodity_offset=1">2</a> | 
                    <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/catalog?on_offer=1&amp;commodity_offset=2">3</a> | 
                    <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/catalog?on_offer=1&amp;commodity_offset=3">4</a> | 
                    <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/catalog?on_offer=1&amp;commodity_offset=4">5</a> | 
                    <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/catalog?on_offer=1&amp;commodity_offset=5">6</a> | 
                    <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/catalog?on_offer=1&amp;commodity_offset=6">7</a>        
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:right">
                    <a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/catalog?on_offer=1&amp;commodity_offset=1">Next</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The doctype is:

html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"

if that makes any difference...

Answer (score 0):

With `loadHTML` I would expect any namespaces to be ignored so try not to use `registerNamespace` at all and then to use `$xpath->query('//div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a');`. As an alternative parse as XML, then using namespaces makes sense.

Comment: if I just use `$xpath->query('//div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a');` the result is empty when I try to echo each item's href with `echo $pages->item($i)->getAttribute('href');`

Comment: Does `$xpath->query('(//div)[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a')` give the desired result? We really need to see a minimal but complete (X)HTML input document and some explanation as to which elements you are looking for to help with the XPath expression itself.

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for taking time to answer. I've updated the question with the html from the site I'm trying to parse. The `$xpath->query('(//div)[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a')` didn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out...

The browser will insert an implicit tag < tbody > when it is not present in the document. The xpath will only process the tags present in the raw HTML string, so I just left out the < tbody > tag.

Old xpath query:

```
$xpath->query('//div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a');
```

New:

```
$xpath->query('//div[2]/table/tr/td[1]/a');
```